# update not specific to certain row

Tags: php, database

I am having issues storing likes/dislikes values to my database, i need each post to have it's own like/dislike column to be stored in its row, and when someone likes the post, for it to just like **that post** not anything else, the issue I am having is it is liking the first entry in the database, can someone give guidance?

if it helps heres a picture of the database
[image]

```
$likes = (empty($_POST['like'])) ? : $_POST['like'] ;
$dislikes = (empty($_POST['dislike'])) ? : $_POST['dislike'] ;
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(isset($_POST['like'])){
$likes1 = $likes+1;
$voted1 = $voted+1;
$query2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (voted, ip) VALUES (:voted, :ip)");
$query2->bindParam(':voted', $voted1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query2->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query2->bindParam(':pid', $pid, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query2->execute();
$update1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE data SET likes = :likes");
$update1->bindParam(':likes', $likes1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update1->bindParam(':quote', $actual_quote, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update1->execute();
header("Location: inspirational.php?");
}

if(isset($_POST['dislike'])){
$dislikes1 = $dislikes+1;
$voted1 = $voted+1;
$query2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (voted, ip) VALUES (:voted, :ip)");
$query2->bindParam(':voted', $voted1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query2->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$query2->execute();
$update1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE data SET dislikes = :dislikes");
$update1->bindParam(':dislikes', $dislikes1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update1->bindParam(':quote', $actual_quote, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update1->execute();
header("Location: inspirational.php?");
}
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row3 = $stmt->fetch();

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE formtype = 'Inspirational' ");
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//delete this-> $info = mysql_fetch_array($query1);   ?
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Questions.</h2>
        <div class="checkboxes"><?php echo htmlentities($row["formtype"]); ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-submit">
        &#8220;<?php echo htmlentities($row["actual_quote"]); ?>&#8221;
    </div>
    <div class="poster">- <?php echo htmlentities($row["poster"]);

if(isset($row3["voted"]) && isset($row3["ip"]))
{
    echo "You have already voted for this.";
}
else
{
    ?>
<form action="" method="post"> 
<input type="submit" name="dislike" value="dislike" />         
<input type="submit" name="like" value="like" />         
</form>        <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Heard of ORM? Like Eloquent? That'd make this A LOT easier to write, use and maintain. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

I already tried that structure on one of my projects. The difference is I tried it on a rating system. I prefer storing likes and dislikes as a JSON text format so you can easily manipulate it.

Likes/Dislike json format

```
{user_id:1}
```

user_id is the user that likes/dislikes a specific posts. 1 means it like/dislike the posts. For example.

```
Like/Dislike Column
{0001:1, 0002:1; 0003:1}
```

You can json_decode this and will output as

> array( [0001] => 1, [0002] => 2, [0003] => 3 )

You can validate if the user like that posts if you use the function array_key_exists. And count it using array_count.

I prefer to do the calculation of likes/dislikes and validation in javascript so it will not slow your application. I'm sure there is an equivalent methods of php for counting and validating in javascript.

Hope this helps.